# Angular text select block by default how to fix

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular, web

You Can add this property's in your Angular Style.Scss or Style.css

```
<pre>
html{ 
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;`enter code here`
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div,br,li,td,article{
    -o-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somehwere?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not a question